# Admob: can i use ADId created for an application in another application?

Tags: android, admob

suppose if i created one ad in one application in admob, can i use it in any other of my apps ? if its possible, lets say i have created multiple applications in admob and got respective AdIds and used all of them in one application, is there any effect on my overall admob revenue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is completely possible and you can do it without any issue.

Admob's 'AdUnit' are unique only if you want to track the reports of your ad units. How they are performing in different countries with impressions and how many click does each Ad Unit have with the cost of click.

In case you use same Ad Unit for all the applications it will be difficult to track the performance of individual app. Though it is completely possible.